# Moq Return a collection with at least one fake object inside it

Tags: c#, moq

How can I return a list of objects, having at least one fake object in the list

I've tried the following:

```
    FacadeMock.Setup(x => x.GetCost(It.IsAny<IContact>()))
        .Returns(() => new List<ICost>().Add(new Mock<ICost>().Object));
```

But it doesn't work
thanks

Comment: In case you were wondering, the statement new List<ICost>().Add(new Mock<ICost>().Object) will return the result of the Add method.  Since add is of type void, nothing gets returned.  Your new solution actually returns the list with the mock object inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the lambda's expression with the statement block like the following code:

```
FacadeMock.Setup(x => x.GetCost(It.IsAny<IContact>()))
    .Returns(() => {
        var myList = new List<ICost>();
        myList.Add(new Mock<ICost>().Object)

        // Create your real object here as much as you want 
        // and use myList.Add to add them to your colllection.

        return myList;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
        FacadeMock.Setup(x => x.GetCost(It.IsAny<IContact>()))
            .Returns(() => new List<ICost>{ new Mock<ICost>().Object });
```

Comment: Or simply: `new [] { new Mock<ICost>().Object }` if you don't need an actual List<T>.